# MVC: OutputCache and extremely slow RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add caching to certain child actions, so I can separately cache parts of a single page.

I need the same controller method to be accessible both from AJAX and with `RenderAction` (or some other embedding method).

I've changed my code to use `RenderAction` and I've found that each `Html.RenderAction` adds around 1 second to the page loading time, when first load is so slow - it's hard to enjoy the fruits of the subsequent loads.

I've seen answers here on SO, advising to stay away from `RenderAction`...

So, what's the best strategy to sidestep the `RenderAction` lag and still be able to cache AND have a single method I can call from both HTML and AJAX? (and.. how to handle cache invalidation in this case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is ajax doing here ?
Are you returning a JSonResult if called from ajax and a ViewResult for normal calls ?

Try to use RenderAction with a razor view. The razor engine is faster.
When the result is cached, renderaction is extremely fast (x1000).

For caching are you using the [OutputCache] attribute ? If so you can not invalidate the cache by yourself (or i don't know about it).

Or maybe you are using OutputCache with VaryByParam parameters which multiplies in-memory caches inneficiently.

Comment: yes, sometimes `JsonResult` and sometimes `View`. I am using the Razor engine - cached serving time is great, but first load is painfully slow. Yes, using OutputCache with VaryByParam (with lots of params.. EDIT: 6)

Comment: you should not have too much params, because the cache will use too much memory. It will recycle the first cached items and slow down the page. Cache memoryUsed = viewText ^ paramValuesCount. If paramsCount=6 and paramValuesCount=1000 memory used = 10K^6000 = overflow) and your cache ... recycles items as soon as it get cached.

Comment: At the moment I'm more worried about the performance of `RenderPartial`, the caching part of the question is more of a conceptual one, of how to DRY when using output cache